# Reordering tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, enums

I a trying to re order cells based on their priority (an enum). I have double checked that my enum values are correct. Here is my enum

```
enum Priority{
    case low
    case neutral
    case high
    case urgent
}
```

As you can see, the lower priority has lower hash values. I am trying to compare two cells;  a cell and the cell above it. If the cell's value is greater than the one above it, it will shift upwards. I obtain the IndexPath of the cell above using

```
var newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1 , section: indexPath.section)
```

After comparing enum values using

```
if(comparePriority.hashValue < priorityValue.hashValue)
```

I attempt to switch the order using

```
tableview.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
```

The result is interesting, I will use pictures to explain. Note that all of this code is in my `cellForRowAt` function and that all cells are given the priority that correspond with their name except for "test", also that these pictures were taken in slow motion meaning that the user wouldn't be able to actually see the switch happening.

Mid-segue
[image: Cells start switching]

Cells finish switching
[image: Cells finish switching]

Comment: So do you want to animate its moving? Otherwise reloadData call after sorting your array will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort your array of items according to these priorities and then do a table reload.

In that way index `0` is simply the first item etc. and you'll get simple code that's not confusing by on the fly sorting/comparing all over the place.

Sorting would look something like (after you've made your `enum` of type `Int` and renamed `priorityValue` to `priority` which I suggest you do):

```
enum Priority: Int
{
    case low     = 0
    case neutral = 1
    case high    = 2
    case urgent  = 3
}

items.sorted(by: { $0.priority < $1.priority })
```

Comment: How would I go about sorting my array in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

You better set priority value explicitly like this.

```
enum Priority: Int {
case low = 0
case neutral = 1
case high = 2
case urgent = 3
}
```

and sort your `dataSource` array like

```
dataSource = dataSource.sorted(by: { $0.priority < $1.priority })
tableView.reloadDate()
```